# Konva JS and React, canvas displaying bad data

Tags: reactjs, canvas, konvajs

I have a fairly complex problem which hopefully someone can lend some insight into.
Recently I've been using `react-konva` to implement the drawing of a large number of points (100->5000) on a canvas. Each point is an object with x and y coordinates, a user value, a date value, etc.

---

Everything works just fine with drawing them, however I started filtering the data and `konva` has been reacting strangely. (To clarify, the filtering works just fine, rendering the filtered data is what screws up).

---

**Despite (correct) data getting rendered into the** `react DOM`, the canvas on screen will randomly choose to either **display the wrong points, no points at all, or display the correct points for several milliseconds before drawing the wrong points into the canvas.**
I'd post code, but I've put over 30 hours into checking the code and all the points get to the `React DOM` as expected. Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be going wrong?

---

Edit 1: Another clarification, the bad renders happen after a filter is modified (so the data is modified) but again, the data coming out of my filtering function is correct, and those points do get through to react, so really it's just happening on a subsequent render of the `konva canvas`.

Comment: Is it hard to help without a demo.

Comment: If I could have provided one, I absolutely would have @iavrton

Comment: how do you use filters? Do correctly recache shape?